# How to change my DNS server provider permanently?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

I want to change my DNS nameserver to GoogleDNS on fedora 25. I edited /etc/resolv.conf from

```
search fritz.box
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

to

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.8.4
```

But if I reconnect to router, the file will revert back to my router's DNS nameserver. 
I followed this https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using this link's tutorial for debian part. But it isn't working.

Can I change nameserver to google's DNS permanently?

P.S: I do not have access to the router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are getting the DNS server from the router and overriding what you set.  To fix this, you must edit `/etc/dhclient.conf`.

Add this line to make sure that it does not override the default DNS servers:

> supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;

Alternatively, you can instruct the DHCP client to not request a DNS server address.

More information can be found with the `man dhclient.conf` command.

Answer (score 1):

Below Solution Worked in my box (Fedora release 25)

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1
```

Added below entries to above file at the bottom.

```
PEERDNS=NO
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

And restarted network (`service network restart`) to ensure that the entries are not modified in `/et/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by going to network manager and editing my connection in IPv4 tab, sliding automatic to manual for DNS and then setting server address to the one I need. (GNOME)
Or I could edit resolve.conf and then change its attribute with option i, like
`chattr +i resolv.conf . Therefore stopping DHCP from editing it again. 
I observed that in xfce4​ - network manager we have to change the DHCP in IPv4 to automatic address but manual DNS in options.